# How to unpack nested tuples in python?

Tags: python, nested, iteration, tuples

Let's say I have users (John, Anna) that can order fruits (oranges, apples) in a quantity of their choice.

Here is what I have done in python :

```
orders = (('John', (('apples', 3), ('oranges', 1))),
          ('Anna', (('oranges', 6))))
```

I'd like to iterate over the orders :

```
for user, order in orders:
    for fruit, quantity in order:
        print "%s wants %d %s" % (user, quantity, fruit)
```

This is the output i'm expecting :

```
John wants 3 apples
John wants 1 oranges
Anna wants 6 oranges
```

I get a `ValueError: too many values to unpack`. What am I doing wrong?
Should I use something else than tuples? Is it my iteration that is bad?

Answer (score 7):

It would have been useful to show the exact traceback.

The error is simply that Anna's order isn't actually a nested tuple: it's a simple tuple. You are missing a comma at the end:

```
orders = (('John', (('apples', 3), ('oranges', 1))),
          ('Anna', (('oranges', 6),)))
#                                 ^ here
```

Remember it's the comma that makes the tuple, not the parentheses.

As others have stated though, nested dicts would be more appropriate here.

Comment: The reason the traceback is showing "too many values to unpack" is because it's iterating through Anna's order, which first tries to unpack `"oranges"` into two variables and can't.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel has given an excellent answer to:

> What am I doing wrong?

But to address your second question:

> Should I use something else than tuples?

I would say that this is a much better fit for a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
>>> orders = {'John': {'apples': 3, 'oranges': 1}, 'Anna': {'oranges': 6}}
>>> for user, order in orders.items():
        for fruit, quantity in order.items():
            print "{0} wants {1} {2}".format(user, quantity, fruit)


Anna wants 6 oranges
John wants 1 oranges
John wants 3 apples
```

*(Note that dictionaries are not guaranteed to retain the order of their contents - if the order is crucial, there is an alternative [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) that guarantees retention of insertion order.)*

This is particularly useful to answer questions like *"how many apples did John want?"*

```
>>> orders['John']['apples']
3
```

which can be altered to guard against someone not having ordered that fruit, for example if you want to find out *"how many apples were ordered in total?"*

```
>>> sum(order.get('apples', 0) for order in orders.values())
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would use not `dict(dict)`, but `list(x)`, where `x` is a simple class, representing person.

```
class Buyer(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.items = {}

  def purchase(self, item, amount=1):
    if item in self.items.keys():
      self.items[item] += amount
    else:
      self.items[item] = amount

orders = []

b1 = Buyer("John")
b1.purchase("apples", 3)
b1.purchase("oranges", 1)
orders.append(b1)

b2 = Buyer("Anna")
b2.purchase("oranges", 6)
orders.append(b2)

for order in orders:
  for thing, num in order.items.iteritems():
    print "%s wants %d %s" % (order.name, num, thing)
```

Comment: You could alter this to move the printing to e.g. `Buyer.print_orders()`

Comment: You can scale this one infinitely :)